# Standard Data Types

Tags: types, language-agnostic, iso, ecma, ieee

I am looking for information regarding data type standardization.

Take for example a double precision floating point value:

> **STANDARDIZATION:**    IEEE 754
>
> **JavaScript:**         Number
>
> **Java:**               double
>
> **C#:**                 double / System.Double
>
> **C/C++:**              double *(compiler dependant implementation)*

The example above illustrates implementations of a double precision floating point value in different programming languages. I would like to know if there is any standardization (for example; ISO, IEEE, ECMA, etc.) of other common data types, specifically:

- signed and unsigned 8bit, 16bit, 32bit and 64bit integers
- single, double and currency/decimal floating point values
- ascii and unicode characters
- boolean
- string

I have already taken a look at [ISO/IEC 11404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11404) but I didn't find it particlarly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your types are addressed here...

The *Common Language Specification* is standardized in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) and implemented in many languages for Microsoft .NET. It was intentionally designed without unsigned integral types. However, the .NET Framework does include them.